# Making 103 from 4 zeroes

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

As the title suggests, the puzzle here is making the number 103 by using exactly four 0s and the following operations:

- $+$ Addition
- $-$ Subtraction
- $\times$ Multiplication
- $\div$ Division
- $\sqrt{a}$ Square Root
- $\sqrt[b]{a}$ Arbitrary Roots
- $!$ Factorial
- $\%$ Percent (e.g. $4\% = 0.04$)

The solution is *slightly* difficult, but it shouldn't be too hard for you crazy puzzlers. Have fun!

Comment: For arbitrary roots, can we pick any b we want, or must we substitute a result for b?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 If you use an arbitrary root, you must substitute a result.

Comment: `0 / 0! = 103`, right?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As
[rand al’thor points out
 in the solution built upon here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50135),
there must be a way to formulate a
$\small 3$ with only
two $\small 0 \kern1mu$s.
 
How promising that...

> ...$~~ 3 = \sqrt{10-1 \, \small\raise.3ex\strut} ~$...

...uses only two $\small 1$s.

And how convenient that
$\small \surd$ and
$ \small \%  $
can combine to scale
$\small  1     $ by any positive power of
$ \small 0.1 \,$.
 
So (with ever fewer operations,
at <del>18</del>  <del>15</del>  **14**) ...

> $\require{begingroup}\begingroup{}  \def \@     #1{{ \sqrt { #1 \, \scriptsize\raise.4ex\strut }       }}{}   \def \sp     {{            \kern     3mu \%                       }}{}    \def \fpp   {{ \small      \kern    2mu  \% \kern1mu \%          }}{}     \def \fp   {{  \small      \kern   2mu   \% \! \raise.4ex\strut }}{}      \def \p   {{    \scriptsize \kern 1mu     \%                   }}{}       \def \E   {  ~~ \equiv ~~ }{}        \def \=  {  ~~   =    ~~ }{}         \def \- {   \,  -    \, }{}          \kern 5em \small\begin{align}{}\normalsize { 0! + \@{\@  { 0!\fp     }\sp \-    0! \fpp    } \over 0!\fp   }{}        &\= {  1 + \@{ \@ {   1\p \!  } \sp \-    1  \p\p   } \over  1 \p   }{}\\[3ex] &\= {  1 + \@{  \@{    .01 \! }  \sp \-   1   \p\p  } \over  1  \p  }{}\\[2ex] &\= {  1 + \@{         .1         \p  \-  1    \p\p } \over  1   \p }{}\\[2ex] &\= {  1 + \@{         .001            - .0001      } \over .01     }{}\\[2ex] &\= {  1 + \@{         .0009                        } \over .01     }{}\\[2ex] &\= {  1 +             .03                            \over .01     }{}\\[2ex] &\E \normalsize 103{}\end{align}\endgroup$

**Initial solution.**
 
More operations but also more symmetry.

> $\begingroup \displaystyle \kern6em{}  \def \@  #1{{ \sqrt { #1 \, }                         }}{}   \def \fp  {{  \small \kern  2mu \%  \raise.4ex\strut }}{}    \def \p  {{   \small \kern 1mu  \%                  }}{}     { 0! + \@{ \@{ 0!\fp\p\p } \, - \, \@{ 0!\fp\p\p\p } } \over 0!\fp }{}\endgroup$

**Backpuzzle.**
 
How about $\boldsymbol{.4}$ with only 3 (three) $\small 0 \kern1mu$s
and just 11 operations?

> $\begingroup{}  \def \@ #1{{ \sqrt  { #1 \scriptsize\raise.4ex\strut }              }}{}   \def \fp {{  \small      \kern  2mu \% \scriptsize\raise.9ex\strut }}{}    \def \p {{   \scriptsize \kern 1mu  \%                            }}{}     \kern 5em \small\begin{align}{}\normalsize         \sqrt { 0!\fp } + \sqrt  {\sqrt{ 0!\fp } - 0!\fp \,    }{}        & ~~   =   ~~\@   {  1\p  } +  \@    { \@  {   1\p } -   1\p  \,   }{}\\[2ex] & ~~   =   ~~ \@  {  .01  } +   \@   {  \@ {   .01 } -   .01   \,  }{}\\[2ex] & ~~   =   ~~  \@ {  .01  } +    \@  {         .1    -   .01    \, }{}\\[2ex] & ~~   =   ~~   \@{  .01  } +     \@ {         .09                 }{}\\[2ex] & ~~   =   ~~        .1    +                   .3{}\\[2ex] & ~~\equiv ~~ \normalsize .4{}\end{align}\endgroup$

$\large($And a ${0! \over 0!\%\%\%}$
        more thanks to rand al’thor for fixing up
        $\scriptsize\sqrt{\%\%\%\%\,\tiny\raise1ex\strut}$
        from the initial solution!
$\large)$

Comment: ^vote with a note: you can replace $\sqrt{0!%%%%}$ by simply $0!%%$. Nice answer!

Comment: Thus the cleanup begins, thank you @rand al'thor!

Comment: The humnification is spreading: first manshu, now me too.

Comment: (Pps., @rand al'thor, the direction is humn $\to$ manshumn $\to$ manshu. See you$\llap{\raise1ex{\underline{~~~~~}}}$ m$\,$e$~~\llap{\raise1ex{\underline{\,}}}$anshu there once all is complete!)

Answer (score 9):

My intended answer:

> $103 = \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{0!\%}\,- \,0!\%}\,\% + \sqrt{0!\%}}{\sqrt{0!\%}\,\%}$

(The strategy used isn't too far off from humn's answer)

Answer (score 8):

**Incomplete answer**

I can do it using five zeroes:

> $\Big(0!+(0!)\%+(0!)\%+(0!)\%\Big)\div(0!)\% = 103.$

In order to reduce this to four, all we need to do is

> find a way to construct the number $3$ using only two zeroes,

because then the final solution will be

> $(0!+3\%)\div(0!)\% = 103.$

Comment: Alternatively, $\frac{0!}{0! \%} + 3$

Answer (score 0):

Will this work(I know it may be a cheating, but thought of giving this).       Most important or unimportant it is with five zeros (if in case op changes his/her mind to have with 5 zeros, then I am ready with my solution after @Rand)

> $$(0!)0(0!)+0!+0!=103$$

Comment: Is that first term supposed to be 101?

Comment: Also, isn't that too many zeroes? I would downvote, but then your score wouldn't be 0 any more.

Comment: @MrLister I wrote but I don't know where I missed the message. By the way, I wrote there are actually 5 zeroes instead of 4. I wrote this when I was going to sleep.(you need to have 125 rep to downvote :)

Comment: @Jacob indeed (I wrote it before but I don't know where is my message)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier:

103 = 0! + 0! + 0! + 0!/%

Comment: % is an operation, you can't divide by it.